# AWK: Basic Line by Line Matching and Field Changing

Tags: awk

I cannot seem to figure out why this won't work.  Please help.  I'm trying to match the value from $7 in file1 into $7 in file2.  I can get this to work when I copy the value from $7 in file1 into $3 in file2 but for some reason AWK doesn't like what I'm doing with $7.  AWK only please.

**Code**

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
       NR == FNR { values[substr($1,0,10) FS $2] = $7; next } 
       (substr($5,0,10) FS $6) in values { $7 = values[substr($1,0,10) FS $2]}1' file1 file2
```

**File 1**

```
LANGBPRJ01.RD.LA    ae31.0  25      400000.0    Default 25
```

**File2**

```
RSMTDSRJ02  ae4.0   null    110 LANGBPRJ01  ae31.0  null    110
```

**Output I see:**

```
RSMTDSRJ02  ae4.0   null    110 LANGBPRJ01  ae31.0      110
```

**Desired Output**

```
RSMTDSRJ02  ae4.0   null    110 LANGBPRJ01  ae31.0  25  110
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$7 = values[substr($1,0,10) FS $2]` should be `$7 = values[substr($5,0,10) FS $6]`

btw fields, strings, arrays, etc. all start at `1` in awk, not `0`, so when you write `substr(string,0,...` that `0` in the 2nd parameter is simply an invalid value and awk treats any invalid value in that context as if it were `1`. You could replace `0` with `"aardvark"` and get the same result. You should be using `substr(string,1,...` instead.

You probably don't actually need the substr()s on $5 of the 2nd file at all since it appears to always be 10 chars.

Finally - use `,` as the array index separator by default, just branch out to FS, OFS, or whatever if you have a specific need,

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
     NR == FNR { values[substr($1,1,10),$2] = $7; next } 
     ($5,$6) in values { $7 = values[$5,$6] } 1' file1 file2
```